# Pandas Dataframe masking issues: referring to previous rows and selecting values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas, and I'm trying to avoid iterating over a DataFrame, and attempting to use vectorisation instead. I am not able to get the results I want; I need help in the more complicated masking and selection statements

This is my code:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

dates = []
temp = []
press = []
vel   = []

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
stime = datetime.strptime('2020-01-06 10:28:16', fmt)
etime = datetime.strptime('2020-04-10 03:43:12', fmt)
td = etime - stime

l = set([random.random() for x in range(0, 1000)])
dates = [((td * x) + stime) for x in random.sample(l, 100)]

for i in range(100):    
    press.append(random.uniform(14,95.5))
    temp.append(random.uniform(-15,45))
    vel.append(random.uniform(50,153))


measurements = {
    'date' :     dates,
    'pressure' : press,
    'velocity' : vel,
    'temperature': temp
}

df = pd.DataFrame(measurements)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.sort_index()

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

# if temp increased from previous row, set flag      
df2['temp_inc'] =  df['temperature'] - df.shift(1)['temperature'] > 0
df2['temp_inc'] = df2['temp_inc'].replace({True: 1, False: 0})

# need to fetch velocity where pressure has increased from previous row, else 0
press_up_mask    =  df.where( (df['pressure'] - df.shift(1)['pressure']) > 0)
#df2['press_spike_velocity']  =  df[press_up_mask]['velocity']

# Need to perform calc based on 'temp_inc' column: if 'temp_inc' column is 1: calculate pressure * velocity, else 0
temp_inc_mask = df2['temp_inc'] == 1
df2['boyle_fact']  =  df[temp_inc_mask]['pressure'] * df[temp_inc_mask]['velocity']

# Get some stats
df2['short_max_temp']     =  df['temperature'].rolling(3).max()
df2['long_min_pressure']  =  df['pressure'].rolling(30).min()

print(df.head())
print(df2.head())
```

How do I correctly calculate columns 'press_spike_velocity' and 'boyle_fact' ?

Comment: Ah, well spotted!

Comment: No problem , what is your expected output? `press_up_mask` should be a boolean if you want to use as a mask for boolean indexing

Comment: instead of `for` loop and append random: `press = np.random.uniform(14, 95.5, 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the computations:

```py
# if temp increased from previous row, set flag      
df2['temp_inc'] =  df['temperature'] - df.shift(1)['temperature'] > 0
# setting int type instead of replace
df2['temp_inc'] = df2['temp_inc'].astype(int)

# need to fetch velocity where pressure has increased from previous row, else 0
press_up_mask = df.where( (df['pressure'] - df['pressure'].shift(1)) > 0)
# set column to velocity then mask in zeros via assignment
df2['press_spike_velocity'] = df['velocity'].copy()
df2['press_spike_velocity'][~press_up_mask] = 0

# Need to perform calc based on 'temp_inc' column: if 'temp_inc' column is 1: calculate pressure * velocity, else 0
temp_inc_mask = df2['temp_inc'] == 1
# same masking approach as above
df2['boyle_fact'] = df['pressure'] * df['velocity']
df2['boyle_fact'][~temp_inc_mask] = 0
```

This is the simplest way to solve your problem with minimal changes to the code itself. If you dig into pandas more you could probably find methods to do this in 1-2 fewer lines via inplace operations but I don't know how much performance or readability you would gain from that.

Comment: On the lines where I am assigning a value - for e.g.: `df2['press_spike_velocity'][~press_up_mask] = 0`, I get the warning: *A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame*  and the dataframe `df2` remains unchanged.